# Account didn't active after I confirmed my email in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, email-verification

I wrote some code in django about registration with a verification email and the email has sent to me and I confirmed it but my acc didn't activate.
I don't know if the problem is with my activate function or what
here is the error I get :
[image]

and this is my activate function:

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and acc_activation.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

and my activation_email.html code :

```
    {% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
pleace click here to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `user.profile.email_confirmed = True` in your logic.

```
    if user is not None and acc_activation.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
```